# Disabling OGR_GPKG_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECK option in QGIS

Tags: qgis, ogr

I am trying to load a bunch of vectors and rasters in a geopackage file.
I was able to load few vectors but then all of a sudden the following warning popped up preventing me to load any more vectors:

```
Failed to import some vector layers!
Opening of data source in update mode failed (OGR: pragma foreign_key_check on 'F:/link/to/my/geopackage.gpkg' failed. You can disable this check by setting the OGR_GPKG_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECK configuration option to NO)
```

I couldn't find a way to set that configuration or to manually override it.

How can I overcome this issue that prevents me from loading any more vector files?

Comment: Instead of disabling the foreign key check you should try to find out why there is a conflict with foreign keys and fix the error.

Comment: please don't use pictures of error messages, it is easy to copy and paste the error text.

Comment: I think I'd be able to answer this question "on-topic", so I'd like to vote to reopen it. There was a discussion about this recently on the qgis dev list http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-Developer-GeoPackages-with-constraint-problems-td5373268.html

Comment: Thanks Matthias, I did read your post a while ago. However, I couldn't figure out neither what the problem was with the rest of my vectors, nor how to implement the fix explained in your post.

Comment: @IanTurton -> Can you please explain why even after the image has been replaced with text, the post has been closed? Thank you

Comment: because not enough people have voted to reopen it - https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions